# Error when creating list from custom template

Tags: document-library, crawling, list-template

When I attempt to create a document library using an existing template I recieve an error "the type of this column cannot be changed because it is currently being indexed"

The error occurs on the 2nd line of code below:

```
SPListTemplate template = web.ListTemplates[Settings.CLTEMP_LISTTEMPLATE];
web.Lists.Add(libName, "Central Library staging area. Files get routed to the main library at the root.", template);
web.Update();
```

Not sure how to resolve and so any help appreciated.

I checked the fields in my schema.xml file and Indexed is set to FALSE for all columns.

thanks,

KS

Comment: What column is indexed in this list template?

Comment: I dont know, I have a bunch of Managed MetaData columns, choices etc. Are some of these automatically indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible Solution:

1. Go to Central Admin site -> Services applications
2. Select the "Managed Metadata Service Proxy" -> Properties
3. Clear the four checkboxes of the managed metadata service connection (regarding CT
   host, managed metadata, etc)
4. Create the site collection
5. Set the "Managed Metadata Service Proxy" properties to its original
   state.

[How to add Proxy to Managed Metadata Proxy](http://everydaysharepoint.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-a-managed-metadata-service-and-content-syndication/)

Comment: I dont see "Managed Metadata Service Proxy", only "Managed Metadata Service" and there are no checkboxes on the page.

Comment: Modified the answer with link to MMD

Comment: I am not publishing any content from one farm to another.

Answer (score 1):

There is index column in your list template

check this blog and after that use your template it may works..

[Metadata disappears for indexed columns that are edited to allow multiple responses.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015261)

Comment: Link is missing.

Comment: Sorry, this does not help me as I can see no indexes in my schema file.